# How to have Windows 7 "All Programs" open in multiple columns?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I would rather have have a bird's-eye view of all my programs than scroll down the programs list. Is there a way to have Windows 7 All Programs list the programs in multiple columns like XP, or did Microsoft remove this capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> did Microsoft remove this capability?

Yes, they did, but all is not lost:

**[Vista Start Menu](http://www.vistastartmenu.com/)** works with Windows 7

[image]

Also available is the **[Classic Start Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2227/get-the-classic-start-menu-in-windows-7/)** (CSMenu) for Windows 7:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can [swap your favorites menu item](http://www.askvg.com/get-windows-xp-styled-classic-all-programs-list-in-windows-vista/) as a programs menu, if you don't really make use of it. Works on Vista and Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: very cute! it doesn't make it columns though, if the list is full, you'll have to scroll, and the old check box 'Scroll Programs' is not present in the Vista/7 start menu properties ... any idea how to change that? http://i365.photobucket.com/albums/oo94/eeemolly/win7progscroll.jpg

Comment: Make the DWORD value `Start_ScrollPrograms` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` and set it to 0?